# Spark partition count is always 1?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I'm running Spark in local mode and I am expecting multiple partitions to be present when doing simple groupBy but the partition count is always coming out as 1:

```scala
val spark = SparkSession.builder()
  .appName("Test App")
  .master("local[5]")
  .getOrCreate()
spark.sparkContext.setLogLevel("OFF")

import spark.implicits._

val simpleData = Seq(("James", "Sales", "NY", 90000, 34, 10000),
  ("Michael", "Sales", "NY", 86000, 56, 20000),
  ("Robert", "Sales", "CA", 81000, 30, 23000),
  ("Maria", "Finance", "CA", 90000, 24, 23000),
  ("Raman", "Finance", "CA", 99000, 40, 24000),
  ("Scott", "Finance", "NY", 83000, 36, 19000),
  ("Jen", "Finance", "NY", 79000, 53, 15000),
  ("Jeff", "Marketing", "CA", 80000, 25, 18000),
  ("Kumar", "Marketing", "NY", 91000, 50, 21000)
)
val df = simpleData.toDF("employee_name", "department", "state", "salary", "age", "bonus")

val df2 = df.groupBy("state").count()

println(df2.rdd.getNumPartitions) // always prints 1
```

Above prints 1. Since the default shuffle partition count is 200, I'm expecting there to be more than 1 partition. I even set the shuffle partition count manually but still getting 1:

```
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.shuffle.partitions", 500)
```

Is some setting not correct, or my understanding is wrong about shuffle partitions?

Comment: Dusable AQE and try again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is due to Adaptative Query Execution which optimizes things at runtime by looking at the actual data volume (among other things).

Turning it off as per below will give you expected behaviour:

```
...
import spark.implicits._
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.adaptive.enabled", false) // <-- this

val simpleData = Seq(("James", "Sales", "NY", 90000, 34, 10000),
...
```

You will then get 200 or any other value you explicitly set. E.g.

```
200
import spark.implicits._
simpleData: Seq[(String, String, String, Int, Int, Int)] = List((James,Sales,NY,90000,34,10000), (Michael,Sales,NY,86000,56,20000), (Robert,Sales,CA,81000,30,23000), (Maria,Finance,CA,90000,24,23000), (Raman,Finance,CA,99000,40,24000), (Scott,Finance,NY,83000,36,19000), (Jen,Finance,NY,79000,53,15000), (Jeff,Marketing,CA,80000,25,18000), (Kumar,Marketing,NY,91000,50,21000))
df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [employee_name: string, department: string ... 4 more fields]
df2: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [state: string, count: bigint]
```

Here a link https://sparkbyexamples.com/spark/spark-adaptive-query-execution/

Comment: Could you explain what AQE is?

Comment: @GaëlJ https://sparkbyexamples.com/spark/spark-adaptive-query-execution/